# Creating objects from big and small classes. (Performance)

Tags: php, performance, oop

Suppose given 2 claas `a` and `b`

`a` class is very big, in it is several dozen methods.

`b` class code is only this:

```
    class b {
        function __construct () {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
```

I want test performance creating objects from this classes, first time, I create object from big class `a` million times in cycle:

```
    $date_1 = microtime(TRUE);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
        $obj = new a();
    }

    $date_2 = microtime(TRUE);

    echo $date_2 - $date_1;
```

result is approximately 0.34 second.

Now I create objects from small class `b` in cycle.

I am wonder, result is more, than first test time, approximately 0.47 second...

Can you tell me, why this happened? or may be I am wrong somewhere in tests ?

Comment: How many tests did you run? I ran some tests with a constructor only class and with a class containing 10 methods, and the results are quite similar.

Comment: I run several tests. and in your case, if results are quite similar, this is also a little surprise, not right?

Comment: Not necessarily imo. While i do not know too much about the internals of php, i was expecting a very small difference (which exists, but at 1 mil iterations is somewhere in the range of 0.00000000001 per insatntiation in my case) because of the differend size for those objects. But other than that should be quite similar i guess, especially if you do not do anything in the constructor.